# How to prevent certain packages from using spring with ArchUnit?

Tags: java, spring, domain-driven-design, hexagonal-architecture, archunit

If I wanted to keep a certain Java package free of 3rd party dependencies with *ArchUnit*, how would I do it?

More specifically I am looking at keeping my domain model in a hexagonal architecture free from spring code.  I specified some rules which I believe ought to prevent the model from using spring.  However, I am able to use spring annotations like `@Component` and `@Bean` without causing a violation.

What I tried so far is

```
layeredArchitecture().
  layer("domain").definedBy(DOMAIN_LAYER).
  layer("application").definedBy(APPLICATION_LAYER).
  layer("primary-adapters").definedBy(PRIMARY_ADAPTERS).
  layer("secondary-adapters").definedBy(SECONDARY_ADAPTERS).
  layer("spring").definedBy("org.springframework..")
  whereLayer("spring").mayOnlyBeAccessedByLayers("primary-adapters", "secondary-adapters", "application").
  because("Domain should be kept spring-free").
  check(CLASSES);
```

As well as

```
noClasses().that().resideInAPackage(DOMAIN_LAYER).
should().dependOnClassesThat().resideInAPackage("org.springframework..").
check(CLASSES);

noClasses().that().resideInAPackage(DOMAIN_LAYER).
should().accessClassesThat().resideInAPackage("org.springframework..").
check(CLASSES);
```

[Here](https://github.com/sebsprenger/hexagon-enforcement) a code example which executes the tests just fine, although `com.example.app.domain.Factory` is importing `org.springframework...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DescribedPredicate:

```
void domainSpring() {
    DescribedPredicate<JavaAnnotation> springAnnotationPredicate = new DescribedPredicate<JavaAnnotation>("Spring filter") {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(JavaAnnotation input) {
            return input.getType().getPackageName().startsWith("org.springframework");
        }
    };
    classes().that().resideInAPackage(DOMAIN_LAYER).should()
            .notBeAnnotatedWith(springAnnotationPredicate).check(CLASSES);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also go with name matching.
So you don't have to write a custom `DescribedPredicate`.

```
 ApplicationCoreMustNotDependOnFrameworks = noClasses()
       .that().resideInAnyPackage(DOMAIN_LAYER)
       .should().dependOnClassesThat().haveNameMatching("org.springframework.")
       .orShould().dependOnClassesThat().haveNameMatching("javax.persistence.*")
       .because("Domain should be free from Frameworks");
```

in my case, I wanted an exception to that rule.
I.e., instead of excluding completely Spring, I wanted to accept the classes in the event package (`EventHanlder`)
so you can replace `"org.springframework"` with `"org.springframework(?!.*event).*"` which is a regular expression